# Appending to the rows and columns to Multi dimensional Arrays Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to append to create a multi dimensional array where it inputs 4 random numbers per row. The code below does not work. How would I be able to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import random 

Array = np.array([[]])

for i in range(3):
    for k in range(4):
        Array[i][k]= np.append(Array[i][k], random.randint(0,9))
```

Expected Output:

```
[[1,3,4,8],
 [2,3,6,4],
 [7,4,1,5],
 [8,3,1,1]]
```

Comment: `Array.shape` is (1,0).  You can't change that by assigning new indices.  That code looks like a cross between Python list code and MATLAB.  You need to spend more time reading the `numpy` introduction.  Don't make assumptions about how `numpy` arrays work.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this**. It is *highly* inefficient to try to create an array like this incrementally using `np.append. If you must do something like this, use a` list`and then convert the resulting list to a`numpy.ndarray` later.

However, in this case, you simply want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,4))
array([[0, 3, 7, 4],
       [6, 4, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 0, 6]])
```

Or perhaps:

```
>>> np.random.randint(0, 10, (4,4))
array([[8, 8, 2, 7],
       [3, 7, 2, 1],
       [5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 2, 7, 9]])
```

Note, `np.random.randint` has an *exclusive* end, so if you want to draw from numbers [0, 9] you need to use `9+1` as the end.